# Optimal path through 2 types of nodes which touches every node of 1st type and at least one node of second type

Tags: python, graph, graph-algorithm, networkx, minimum-spanning-tree

I am trying to solve a complicated problem which I believe simplifies down to solving a weighted undirected graph like the following. The graph would actually have multiple parallel edges though only single edges shown here.

               `S1
              /  \
           3 /    \ 1
            /      \
           A----1---B---100---S3
           |        |
          10        10
           |        |
           D----1---C
           \        /
          3 \      / 1
             \    /
               S2`

There are 2 types of nodes:
{S1, S2, S3}
{A, B, C, D}

The answer would be the optimal set of minimum cost paths to connect nodes in {A,B,C,D} to 1 and only 1 of {S1, S2, S3}.   The "S" type nodes are optional in the sense that if the least cost path went from S1-A-B-C-D without using S2 or S3, that would be correct.   A path cannot however exist that doesn't include 1 and only 1 of the "S" type nodes.

The above graph would intuitively solve to 2 paths:

`S1 -> B -> A

S2 -> C -> D`

S3 would not connect to anything.

As stated, this is a simplification of a much larger problem, but I'm fairly new to graph theory and uncertain of the best way to approach this.

Additionally, I am using the networkx python library if there is a straightforward way to approach this with that library.

Comment: Here is what I thought would work: `G=nx.Graph()` ;  then `G.add_edges_from([('S1','A',{'weight':2.5}), ('S1','B', {'weight':1}), ('A','D',{'weight':10}), ('B','S3',{'weight':100}), ('B','C',{'weight':10}), ('A','B',{'weight':1}), ('D','C',{'weight':1}), ('D','S2.5',{'weight':2}), ('C','S2',{'weight':1})])` ; Then  `for S in ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']:
    G.add_edge('x', S, {'weight':0})` ; then `nx.single_source_dijkstra(G,'x')`

Comment: I've been playing with that.  I see the 2 expected paths in the results, but I'm not certain I would be able to tell that those are the ones to choose.

Comment: I've given an answer, but highlighted a possible problem depending on how you define optimal.  Let me know if it works - if not I'll delete so that others are more likely to answer.

Comment: For what it's worth: the version I *didn't* answer feels NP-complete to me.  I may be wrong however.

Answer (score 0):

**Note to others - this is only an approximation to the correct answer.  If you have an answer please post it**:

Here's the issue with this answer: let's look at a triangle consisting of S, A, B with S-A having weight 1, S-B having weight 1.5 and A-B having weight 1.  Depending on what you mean by optimal: you may think S-B-A which has a total weight of 2 is better than S-B, S-A which has total weight 2.5.  This answer will give the one which has the shortest path to each node, rather than a global minimum.

```
import networkx as nx
G=nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([('S1','A',{'weight':2.5}), ('S1','B', {'weight':1}), ('A','D',{'weight':10}), ('B','S3',{'weight':100}), ('B','C',{'weight':10}), ('A','B',{'weight':1}), ('D','C',{'weight':1}), ('D','S2',{'weight':2.5}), ('C','S2',{'weight':1})])
for S in ['S1', 'S2', 'S3']:
    G.add_edge('x', S, {'weight':0})
paths = nx.single_source_dijkstra(G,'x')
paths
>({'A': 2, 'B': 1, 'C': 1, 'D': 2, 'S1': 0, 'S2': 0, 'S3': 0, 'x': 0},
  {'A': ['x', 'S1', 'B', 'A'],
  'B': ['x', 'S1', 'B'],
  'C': ['x', 'S2', 'C'],
  'D': ['x', 'S2', 'C', 'D'],
  'S1': ['x', 'S1'],
  'S2': ['x', 'S2'],
  'S3': ['x', 'S3'],
  'x': ['x']})
```

Note I changed some weights from 2 to 2.5 to avoid ambiguity (more than one cost 2 path to 'A' in your example).

Now, any path which is contained in another path can be tossed.  So iterate through the paths and track any nodes that are reached before the final node.

```
removable_nodes = set({})
for (target,path) in paths[1].items():
    for node in path[2:-1]:
        removable_nodes.add(node)
removable_nodes
> {'B', 'C'}
```

This means that the paths you need are the ones to 'A' and 'D'.

Comment: The stated potential problem does invalidate the solution based on what I've defined as optimal.  However, this could give a reasonable estimate of the correct answer within acceptable time.  I'll give it a try on a larger graph and report back.

Comment: I tested on a larger set and this solution produced a higher cost than some other approximations I've tried.  It seems like a solution should yield a minimum spanning tree from each S to each node that "belongs" to it - just impossible to know what belongs to what beforehand.  Leading me to suspect NP-Complete as well.